# How to mount a NAS from command line with a space in the username

Tags: macos, mount, nas, smb, smbfs

I am trying to mount a SMB network drive from my Mac terminal. The user id is *firstname lastname* with a space in between. I have tried all sorts of combinations but none of these are working.

```
mount_smbfs //firstname\ lastname@server/home /Volumes/home

mount_smbfs //"firstname lastname"@server/home /Volumes/home

mount_smbfs //firstname" "lastname@server/home /Volumes/home

mount_smbfs //firstname\040lastname@server/home /Volumes/home
```

Either I am getting URL parsing failed or usage error or incorrect username (not an error but it's not able to authenticate). It however works for username with no spaces or special characters.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried:  mount_smbfs //"firstname lastname"@server/home /Volumes/home?

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well

Comment: Updated the post to include this

Comment: Apparently it works with `%20` in the share name. It’s worth a try I guess!

Comment: Daniel - this works... 

mount_smbfs //firstname%20lastname@server/home /Volumes/home 

I guess because the share name combined with user id and password is parsed as a uri - so the percent encoding works

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel B commented, substitute any space with `%20`.

Comment: This is it right here. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try like this:-

[root@test ProductServers]# ls -l | tail -1
drwxrwxr-x 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody  8192 Mar  6 21:04 TST Servers <-----

[root@test shares]# cd **ProductServers/TST\ Servers/**

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Did you tried this way?

mount_smbfs //firstname\ lastname/@server/home /Volumes/home

Comment: He did. It’s in the question.

Comment: biz - if your suggestion was to append a / at the end it did not work. The share name along with user id and password is parsed as a uri